# Make array_unique() case-insensitive

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, unique, case-insensitive

```
$tags_array = explode(',', $tagss);
```

this gives result like.

> Array ( [0] => Katha [1] => pooja [2] => singer [3] => katha )

when i use array_unique not working gives same result.

```
//print_r($tags_array);
print_r(array_unique($tags_array));
```

> Array ( [0] => Katha [1] => pooja [2] => singer [3] => katha )

Comment: Check out this function, it includes a case sensitive option: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#33517

Comment: Because `Katha` and `katha` are __unique__

Answer (score 0):

You have no duplicate values in your array. From the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

> Note: Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2 i.e. when the string representation is the same, the first element will be used.

However, there is a solution in the [user-contributed notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#78801) on that page:

```
function array_iunique($array) { 
    $lowered = array_map('strtolower', $array); 
    return array_intersect_key($array, array_unique($lowered)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your input array is collection of non-numeric strings, you can loop over the array and populate a new array with temporary, lowercase keys and use the null coalescing assignment operator to keep only the first occurring (case-insensitive) value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UeiLP))

```
$array = explode(',', 'Katha,pooja,singer,katha');

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result[strtolower($value)] ??= $value;
}
var_export(array_values($result));
// ['Katha', 'pooja', 'singer']
```

By replacing the `??=` with `=`, you will effectively retain the latest occurring value per case-insensitive key. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nmWXB))

```
// ['katha', 'pooja', 'singer']
```